# If a sentence include a specific word, make each letter in a different color, javascript

Tags: javascript

can anyone assist with a solution?

```
// <div id="here">Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car and a rainbow dog</div>

let placeHere = document.getElementById("here");

const colors = ["red", "orange", "purple"];

const applyRainbow = (word) => {
  const letters = word.split("");

  const wordNode = document.createElement("span");
  wordNode.innerHTML = letters
    .map(
      (letter, index) =>
        `<span class="${colors[index % colors.length]}">
       ${letter}
       </span>`
    )
    .join("");

  return wordNode;
};

placeHere.innerHTML += applyRainbow("rainbow");
```

any tip for trying to color the sting "rainbow" to a different color based on the colors constant?

Comment: Your structure is odd. `applyRainbow` returns a `span` node and not a string. So using it you need like `applyRainbow("rainbow").innerHTML` or `append()` the whole node. Else just return the mapped and joined array to return a string and remove `wordNode` entirely. `return word.split('').map(...).join('')`.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to simplify the code as much as I could. You can just add more colors in the array and it is supposed to work.

```js
let placeHere = document.getElementById("here");

const colors = ["red", "orange", "purple"];

const applyRainbow = (word) => {
  const letters = word.split("");

  return letters.map((le, index) => `<span style="color: ${colors[index % colors.length]}">${le}</span>`).join('');
};

placeHere.innerHTML = placeHere.innerHTML.replace('rainbow', applyRainbow("rainbow"));
```

```html
<div id="here">Mr Blue has a blue house and a blue car and a rainbow dog</div>
```

**EDIT**: Also, noticed the method can be turned to a 1-liner:

```
const applyRainbow = word => word.split("").map((le, index) => `<span style="color: ${colors[index % colors.length]}">${le}</span>`).join('');
```